# Structure of QuickTime's 'dref' atom 'alis' element

Tags: alias, quicktime

I need to rewrite a QuickTime reference movie, making it point to another set of files.
I'm working in Windows environment, so I don't have acces to the QuickTime API, and being the referenced files unaccesible, I can't also use the COM interface to load the movie because it can't resolve the referenced paths.

The documentation in the "QuickTime File Format Specification" says that the 'dref' atom can have a list of 'alis', 'url ' and 'rsrc' data references. In this case I need to parse the 'alis' elements. According to the reference, "Data reference is a Macintosh alias".

So long, I have not been able to see a declaration of the structure or any related information. Do you know the structure of an alias record? Where can I find detailed information about it's structure?

Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: I think I've just found a non official documentation: [link](http://xhelmboyx.tripod.com/formats/alias-layout.txt)

Answer (score 2):

The format is very similar to the sort of alias that you could generate in the Finder by right-clicking an item, and creating an alias to it.

Aside: When the QuickTime format was originally specified, Apple intelligently chose to incorporate a number of other standards and paradigms that were extensively already being used elsewhere in the OS.  This is one of the reasons why QT is (or was) able to do really clever things like reference movies.  Unfortunately, there's also now a lot of cruft leftover from OS features that are no longer relevant (ie. AppleShare).  Back in its heyday, QuickTime was *slick*, especially compared to its competitors; today, it's vastly underappreciated due to the buggy Windows port, and the relatively low processing power of the desktop systems of its time.

Back ontopic, unfortunately, the format for alias files is not an open/published standard, and there is precious little documentation on the topic on the 'net.   There's one really  [old doc](http://xhelmboyx.tripod.com/formats/alias-layout.txt) that deconstructs the alias format used in Mac OS Classic.  Although the structure used in OS X is very similar, the alias files themselves tend to be much larger, as they contain numerous extra data strings at the end of the file that are not documented in the above-linked documentation.

Also, aliases created in the finder *do* look a bit different from the ones contained within the dref atom, although I've never run through them bit-by-bit to deduce the actual differences.  If you want to take a peek at what those files, and have the OS X Developer Tools installed, you can run

```
    setfile -a a [filename]
```

on a Finder-generated alias to strip the file of its alias-ness so that you can look at its contents in a hex editor (otherwise, the OS will just redirect you to the linked file - doh!).  You can re-set the file's alias attribute, or arbitrarily designate any file as an alias by running

```
    setfile -a A [filename]
```

Unfortunately, during my experiments, dumping the `alis` portion of a QT movie's `dref` atom has never seemed to generate an alias that Mac OS was able to interpret.

Fortunately (or not, as it was in my case), the functions that Mac OS allegedly uses to create/handle aliases are part of a public API called the [Alias Manager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Alias_Manager/Reference/reference.html), which is part of the very-low-level CoreServices framework.  If you've got time to delve into this further, you can write some code to experiment with Mac OS's built-in alias-generating and interpreting capabilities.

Unfortunately, if you're dealing with an old/buggy file, you have no way of knowing if the file was actually generated by CoreServices' Alias Manager, or if that framework has changed/evolved/regressed since then.  Because it's a closed format, 3rd-party developers who opt to not use the Alias Manager can only take guesses as to the format's "legal" structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this Java program](http://onjava.com/onjava/2003/02/19/qt_file_format.html) to see what is in the header, and extract data (it's a bit old, but may still work).  What is more useful, though, is the thorough discussion by the author about the Quicktime header.

But I think you may just be looking for the Apple documentation, [currently found here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFPreface/qtffPreface.html).