# MP4 container parsing: What is 'Alias Data Handler' for?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I have an mp4 file which I am parsing with [this](https://github.com/lieff/minimp4) demuxer lib. I stumbled upon a bug when trying to identify a track type. MP4 container keeps this info in `hdlr` box. In the docs and in the lib there are only two options '`vide`' or '`soun`',but in this case I am getting '`alis`'.
While debugging the lib to see how I get this value I noticed that the parser hits '`hdlr`' twice: first time setting '`vide`' for the only video track in the file, and second time overwriting with '`alis`'.
I have loaded the video into MP4 Explorer GUI app and here is what I see:

[image]

Indeed,there is second hdlr box there,which doesn't exist in other mp4 files I tried to parse. My questions are:

1. What is this token for?
2. When is it inserted into mp4?
3. Can I just discard 'alis' when encountering one during the parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From some research...

**(1) What is this token for?**

The **alis** atom is for listing a [file alias](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/alias#:%7E:text=(2)%20In%20the%20Mac%2C,not%20remove%20the%20original%20file.) (or shortcut) to an external resource/URL (*eg:* a stored file).

**(2) When is it inserted into mp4?**

An **alias** atom is usually found in QuickTime MOV files (though it's not illegal to be placed inside an MP4). This "file alias" is something QuickTime player would have responded to (such as for example launching a web page URL during playback).

This other [Answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9217103/2057709) a link with a [guidance](https://xhelmboyx.tripod.com/formats/alias-layout.txt) on the data structure of this atom.

**(3) Can I just discard `alis` when encountering one during the *(miniMP4)* parsing?**

There's no other choice, the [miniMP4](https://github.com/lieff/minimp4) library [does not even have code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jct9D.png) for handling `alis` data.
Yes you can safely skip it. It is not mandatory for playback.

**PS:** 
I wonder if your MP4 is possibly a renamed MOV file? 
(Both formats use same structure, but sometimes there is MP4-specific contents).

Comment: No, it is not  a renamed MP4  file. I have encoded it with Adobe After Effects. Maybe their muxer is configured to insert this box for some reason. Great answer,thanks.

Comment: @MichaelIV Thanks for accepting. Interesting to know about the After Effects metadata. It makes sense because it's a studio-level production tool. The shortcut could usefully point to an assets folder or some parent/home directory as specific to that AE project file.